# Refactoring scala match case for list of strings

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

I have the following:

```
def myFunc(str: String): Something => {

    str match {
        case "a" | "a1" | "abc" | "qwe" | "23rs" => Something
        case _ => None
    }    
}
```

The string list could be very long, I'd like to extract that to a function. I don't really know what to search for, since doing

```
def isSomething(str: String): Boolean => {
  List("a","a1","abc","qwe","23rs").contains(str)
}
```

but `case isSomething => Something` doesn't work

Comment: Use Option monad it would help

Answer (score 1):

Your `str` is a String hence won't match `isSomething` which is of Boolean type.  Another issue with your sample code is that `None` is of Option type, so it would make more sense to have your match cases return the same type.  Here's one approach using `guard` for the `contains` condition:

```
val list = List("a", "a1", "abc", "qwe", "23rs")

val s = "abc"

s match {
  case s if list contains s => Some(s)
  case _ => None
}
// res1: Option[String] = Some(abc)
```

Comment: That pattern match is a rather complex way of saying `if  (list contains s) Some(s) else None`

Comment: Agreed `if/else` is more simple and direct.  I kept pattern matching in the answer mainly to follow OP's apparent intention of using it (while removing the need of expressing the list content in the match cases as the list grows).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answers seem to cover fixing up the use of option, or moving away from pattern matching (a simple use of guards isn't really pattern matching, IMO)

I think you may be asking about extractors. If so, this might be closer to what you want:

```
  case class Something(str: String)

  // define an extractor to match our list of Strings

  object MatchList {
    def unapply(str: String) = {
      str match {
        case "a" | "a1" | "abc" | "qwe" | "23rs" => Some(str)
        case _                                   => None
      }
    }
    }

    def myFunc(str: String): Option[Something] = {

      // use our new extractor (and fix up the use of Option while we're at it)    
      str match {
        case MatchList(str) => Some(Something(str))
        case _              => None
      }
    }

// Couple of test cases...
    myFunc("a")    // Some(Something(a))
    myFunc("b")    // None
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have used wrong `=>` operator while defining the function.

```
scala> def isSomething(str: String): Boolean = {
     |   List("a","a1","abc","qwe","23rs").contains(str)
     | }
isSomething: (str: String)Boolean

scala> def myFunc(str: String): String = {
     | 
     | str match {
     | case str if(isSomething(str)) => "Something"
     | case _ => "None"
     | }
     | }
myFunc: (str: String)String

scala> myFunc("a")
res9: String = Something
```

I don't know what is something so i have treated it as a string. You could modify it according to your use case.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
val list = List("a", "a1", "abc", "qwe", "23rs")

def myFunc(str: String): Option[String] = {
  list.contains(str) match {
    case true => ??? //calling something function should return Some
    case false => None
  }
}
```

`Option[String]` can be changed according to the return type you have , but `None` suggests that the true case should return `Option` type . So `String` can be changed to your desired *datatype*